# How can I use Bitcoind on Ubuntu if I installed from PPA?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu

I have two transactions that won't go through. The first one I [image: first one] I sent with a zero transaction fee by accident and the second one I [image: second one] I sent with a fee of .00022324. Neither is going through. I read [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it?rq=1) question and one of the answers said that

> What can I do to speed-up the transaction’s confirmation?
>
> Nothing. The next best thing is to cancel and resend the transaction.
>
> Make a note of the individual bitcoin address(es) that the unconfirmed transaction was sent from.
>       Wait a few days until your wallet stops broadcasting the transaction (or for immediate results, run Bitcoin Core with the -zapwallettxes option)
>       Send all your bitcoins from the addresses recorded in step 1 to a new address with the recommended or higher than recommended fee.
>       Make original transaction again using the recommended fee.

I wanted to try the -zapwallettxes option but when I try to run bitcoind from terminal it doesn't work. And since I installed from PPA I can't find where the binary was put.

Comment: `And since I installed from PPA I can't find where the binary was put.` What does `which bitcoind` return?

Comment: It shows nothing. No error, nothing at all.

Comment: You seem to be running bitcoin-qt, not bitcoind.

Comment: I didn't know they were separate. Is there anything I can do now then besides waiting?

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed `bitcoin-qt` only.
You should install it first.

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
```

Comment: Or you can call `bitcoin-qt -zapwalletxes`

Answer (score 1):

I'm stealing [Pieter's comment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43361/how-can-i-use-bitcoind-on-ubuntu-if-i-installed-from-ppa#comment56312_48517), because it should be an answer. ;)

`Bitcoin-Qt` and `bitcoind` are two separate programs although they share most of their code base.

You can just call

```
bitcoin-qt -zapwalletxes
```

instead.